# Node JS API: Return JSON to user, after service is done.

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, watson

I'm currently using node.js to create a post-upload API, to upload an image, which is processed by the Watson Visual Recognition Service. This returns a JSON, which is currently logged to the console. 
**Is there a way to send this JSON back to the user, after the process is done?** 
I'm a total newbie to Node.js, so I really appreciate your help.

This is my code:

```
// initialising ...  

app.post( '/detectFaces', avatarUpload, ( req, res ) => { 

    avatarUpload( req, res, ( err ) => {

        if ( err || !req.file )
            return res.send({ error: 'invalid_file' })

        console.log( req.file );

        var path = req.file.path;
        var name = req.file.filename;  

        var params = { 
            images_file: fs.createReadStream(path)
        };   

        //Call to the visual recognition Service
        visual_recognition.detectFaces(params, function(err, res){ 
            if(err) 
                console.log(err); 
            else  
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));   

        });  

        //The JSON of the visual Rec Service should send here. 
        res.send({ 'status' : 'check', url: 'uploads' + '/' + filename }) 


    }) 
    var params = { 
            images_file: fs.createReadStream(path)
        };    


}); 


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Upload Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
visual_recognition.detectFaces(params, function(err, result){ 
    if(err) 
        console.log(err); 
    else  
        res.status(200).json(result)   
});
```

Comment: "Use this" answers are not useful. Explain *what* you did, and *why*. (Also: Please don't post incomplete answers like the first version of this one and then go back and edit them to make them complete. [In this case, it was a ninja edit.] Write a complete answer to start with.)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! This change evokes an error: "Can't send headers after they are sent." Is there a way to make the function wait for the response of the visual Service?

Comment: @JSt: It would have been useful if Jeet had mentioned you also need to remove your current `res.send({ 'status' : 'check', url: 'uploads' + '/' + filename })` line. The `res.status(200>json(result)` **replaces** that, and since it occurs within the recognition callback, it waits for that callback before sending the response.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, this makes sense - I modified the code (see top) - But now it returns a reference error: "json is not defined". Do you have an idea why?

Comment: please use `res.status(200).json(result)` not `res.status(200>json(result))` the difference is `>` vs `)`